# How to find and replace between two files using a macro in notepad++

Tags: macros, notepad++

Iv tried multiple different ways to replace text between two files using a macro but I cant get it to work. My understanding of recording macros in notepad++ is that you can only use keystrokes to perform a command and I did just that and when I played it back it doesn't replace anything.

File_1

```
7248683:1
9476913:467 
7603090:2367
2033565:24
4730634:56789
6815648:325
2032668:57893
7930455:53
2199279:569231
8913826:6783
```

File_2

```
user:2199279
user:4730634
user:7248683
user:8913826
user:2032668
user:7930455
user:9476913
user:6815648
user:2033565
user:7603090
```

I'm trying to replace 7248683 in file_2 with the number right of the Colon in file_1 which would be 1 in this case, and so on throughout the entire file_2 document.

Comment: I would do text to columns in Excel based on the colon (separate string based on delimiter), then do vlookups on the user id code and pipe in the answer from file1. I think your approach with macros may be overly contrived. You could do find replace in vba.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the replacements in the following way:
In a new Notepad++ document, paste in the contents of File_2, and then put the contents of File_1 in the same document beneath the contents of File_2, like this:

```
user:2199279
user:4730634
user:7248683
user:8913826
user:2032668
user:7930455
user:9476913
user:6815648
user:2033565
user:7603090

7248683:1
9476913:467 
7603090:2367
2033565:24
4730634:56789
6815648:325
2032668:57893
7930455:53
2199279:569231
8913826:6783
```

Now do a regex Find-and-Replace (CHECK the box next to ". matches newline"):

Find what:

```
user:(\d+)(.*?^\1:(\d+))
```

Replace with:

```
user:$3$2
```

If there aren't a lot of replacements to make, you can just keep hitting the "Replace" button to do all the replacements. Otherwise, you can use a macro to make it repeat the replacement.

Results when performed on the example data:

```
user:569231
user:56789
user:1
user:6783
user:57893
user:53
user:467
user:325
user:24
user:2367

7248683:1
9476913:467 
7603090:2367
2033565:24
4730634:56789
6815648:325
2032668:57893
7930455:53
2199279:569231
8913826:6783
```